# c# FileSystemWatcher somehow stops watching network folder

Tags: c#, service, filesystemwatcher

I have a processor developed in c# and running as a service that is set to watch a folder on the network for any files created with a *.req extention which normally works as desired, but once in a while it seems to stop watching usually because the server the network folder is on gets rebooted or something.  While I have a task scheduler which automatically restarts this program at midnight on a daily basis, is there any way I can better determine how to restart watching again if nothing occurs for a prolonged duration?  Here's my source code snippet as even error handling doesn't seem to trigger.

```
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = GlobalVars.REQpath;  // ie. \\fmserv\reqfolder\
        // Only watch *.req files.
        watcher.Filter = "*.req";
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
        watcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnError);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
//
// more code here...
//
    private static void OnError(object source, ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.GetException().GetType() == typeof(InternalBufferOverflowException))
        {
            logWriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + ": Error: File System Watcher internal buffer overflow");
        }
        else
        {
            logWriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + ": Error: Watched directory not accessible");
        }
        ((FileSystemWatcher)source).EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        //service should automatically restart application
        //System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
        //System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();   // service automatically restart?

    }
```

Comment: The Error event will fire, don't ignore that.

Comment: I edited my post to include error handling as it should've written to a log file which apparently it's not for some reason unknown.